# calling a function int strrindex(char s[], char t[]) without passing the size parameter in c

Tags: c, arrays

My professor wants us to create this method:

```
int strrindex(char s[], char t[])
```

in a separate file from main and have it return the index of the right-most occurrence of t in s. My first thought was to traverse the array from right to left, find the first occurrence of t[0] and then check if the rest of the sequence matches, if not continue searching right to left for the next character that matches t[0]. Easy enough except I can't get the size of the array since it was passed as a parameter and is now a pointer so I don't know what to put in the for loop to loop through the array. Similar questions suggest passing the size as a param but the param list must be char s[] and char t[] for this assignment.

So my question is how can I do get the size of the array without changing the param list? My only other idea would be to first find the size by looping from the start of the array and finding the '\0' character but that seems cumbersome and inelegant. Is there any simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: If `s` and `t` are null-terminated strings, you’ll have to loop until the null terminator, yes. If you prefer, you can call `strlen()` to do that for you. It might feel wrong, but… them’s the breaks!

Comment: "...but that seems cumbersome" -- welcome to C. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any simpler way to accomplish this?

No. You can use `strlen()` to do that for you, but it's doing the same thing under the hood.